# Can I publish multiple apps with different names and interfaces on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Can I publish multiple apps with different package names & different UI Colors? In Google play TOS and Content Policy there is a line that states Do not post repetitive content. If I have multiple apps which contain the same code, the same UI but with different colours & different names, Am I in violation of Google Play Content Policy?

Comment: `am I in violation of Google Play Content Policy?` this is impossible for us to answer here, you'll have to consult with a lawyer, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You have to change more than just the UI colors.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out! You will very probably be in violation of the repetitive content rules. Be very carefull with this. Google is very strict with this (too strict to my taste) en will bann your developer account from Google Play.